# Replacing values in vector using map in R

Tags: r

I have the following map:

```
map
# non.MMC '#ffffff'
# MMC '#000000'
```

And the following table:

```
temp
#   value   color
# 1 -13.994 non.MMC
# 2 -13.992 non.MMC
# 3 -13.984 non.MMC
# 4 -13.983 non.MMC
# 5 -13.962 non.MMC
# 6 -13.907 non.MMC
# 7 -13.816 non.MMC
# 8 -13.773 MMC
```

I want to replace the values in the color column as per its respective value in `map`. So I am using this code:

```
finalData <- data.frame(provean=temp$value,color=map[temp$color])
finalData
    # provean   color
    # -13.994   #000000
    # -13.992   #000000
    # -13.984   #000000
    # -13.983   #000000
    # -13.962   #000000
    # -13.907   #ffffff
```

I don't understand why the replacement values are switched. I see #000000 when I expect #ffffff and viceversa.

Comment: Possibly `color` column is of type factor. Maybe try `as.character(temp$color)`.

Comment: That worked, do you wanna post it as an answer (maybe with a small explanation) so I can accept it